# Mute HTML validation message while typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, client-side-validation

Steps to reproduce the issue:

- Set an input of type email / phone
- Set the input as required
- Hit form submit on the wrong pattern for email
- The HTML validation message should be now visible.
- Keep entering text into the input box

On entering the text in the input box after the validation message has been kicked in, the validation message persists and gets displayed on every keystroke.

I even tried setting `setCustomValidity("")` on keyup event but that does not help either.

Here is an [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pmtbuk30/8/).

Here is a gif of the problem: 
You can see that until I add `@gmail.com` to the email input, it keeps showing the HTML validation.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Source code for the same.
HTML

```
<form>

  <p>
    <label for="t2">What's your e-mail?</label>
    <input id="email" type="email" id="t2" name="email" required>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

JS

```
$("#email").on("keyup", function (e) {
    if (e.target.value.lenth !== 0) {
    e.target.setCustomValidity("");
  }
});
```

Comment: What about utilizing [form novalidate](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_novalidate.asp) and then building your own validation handler?

Comment: Please include all code relvant to the question, in the question itself. External references should only by used as an optional supplement.

Comment: @JonP Apologies. I wasn't well aware of that practice. Let me add the source code.

Comment: @Volomike If I use the novalidate handler, won't that stop checking for validity on form submit?

Comment: Yes, but you can intercept form submit and do your own checks before allowing the submit to go through.

Comment: true. But the whole point of using HTML5 validation was to avoid that extra bit of code.

Answer (score 1):

When the user presses `enter` and the input validation fails, that input fires an `invalid` event. So, you can add an `invalid` handler to customize (and possibly prevent) the resulting behavior. The `invalid` event does *not* get triggered by further inputs of normal characters, but the invalid pop-up *will* keep appearing as long as the input remains invalid *and focused*. When the input is unfocused (blurred), the validation pop-up will disappear. It will re-appear only *after* the user re-focuses the `input` *and* presses `enter` when the input text is still invalid.

So, one possible solution is to add an `invalid` listener that keeps track of whether the error pop-up is showing or not. Then, add a `keydown` listener that checks if the pop-up is showing. If the pop-up is showing, `blur` and then `focus` the element, so as to make the pop-up disappear until the next time the user presses `enter`:

```js
let errorShowing = false;
$("#email")
.on('invalid', (e) => {
  errorShowing = true;
})
.on("keydown", function(e) {
  if (!errorShowing) return;
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.blur();
    this.focus();
  });
  errorShowing = false;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <label for="t2">What's your e-mail?</label>
  <input id="email" type="email" id="t2" name="email" required>
</form>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: I researched and checked for Chrome, Firefox, and Opera, and they all seem to behave as desired - once the user presses something other than "enter", the error popup, if it exists, will disappear.

Comment: It does not seem to happen in this case.

Comment: What is "in this case"? Can you elaborate?